# Django South alternative?

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south

After reading some older posts about Django South's features, I began wondering why there wasn't a similar tool built in to Django itself.  Then I was curious if maybe something *had* been added these last few years.

Has something been added?

Are there any alternatives to South, or is it the accepted way of handling migrations and such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same thought django core developers had. Since [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/), [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/) is a built-in feature:

> Django now has built-in support for schema migrations. It allows
>   models to be updated, changed, and deleted by creating migration files
>   that represent the model changes and which can be run on any
>   development, staging or production database.

Note that 1.7 is not a stable version at the moment.

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer.  I have been reading the documentation for 1.6, and was unaware of this plan for the next release.

Comment: I presume that a negative vote-total means I asked a good question?

Comment: @Calculon I personally think your question doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: Is South now redundant for Django 1.11 and later, or is there still some benefit in using it?